# How to implement documentation in macro?

Tags: vba, excel

How to implement documentation in macro?
I have written a custom function for my excel sheet. But I don’t know how to implement documentation so that if the function is typed in the function-bar an explanation shows up like the standard functions in excel do.

Is it possible to implement that documentation?

Code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
End Sub

Function AFRONDENONZEKERHEID(n As Double, decimalePlaatsen As Integer, Optional toggle As Boolean = False)
If n = 0 Then
    Exit Function
End If

If toggle Then
    AFRONDENONZEKERHEID = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(n, decimalePlaatsen)
    Exit Function
End If

Dim afgerond As Double
Dim procentueleAfnamen As Double

afgerond = Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(n, decimalePlaatsen)
procentueleAfnamen = (afgerond - n) / n * 100


If procentueleAfnamen <= -5 Then
    AFRONDENONZEKERHEID = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(n, decimalePlaatsen)
Else
    AFRONDENONZEKERHEID = afgerond
End If

End Function
```

(sorry for the Dutch variables)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it possible to implement that documentation?

The answer is yes.

You can run a routine to register your function. The routine would use the [Macro.Options method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/Ff838997.aspx).

The following example of how to [register a UDF](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/user-defined_function_argument_descriptions_in_excel_2010/) comes from John Walkenbach:

> Here's a simple (but very useful) user-defined function:

```
Function EXTRACTELEMENT(Txt, n, Separator) As String
     EXTRACTELEMENT = Split(Application.Trim(Txt), Separator)(n - 1)
End Function
```

> Here's a VBA macro that provides a description for the EXTRACTELEMENT function, assigns it to a function category, and provides a description for each of its three arguments:

```
Sub DescribeFunction()
    Dim FuncName As String
    Dim FuncDesc As String
    Dim Category As String
    Dim ArgDesc(1 To 3) As String

    FuncName = "EXTRACTELEMENT"
    FuncDesc = "Returns the nth element of a string that uses a separator character"
    Category = 7 'Text category
    ArgDesc(1) = "String that contains the elements"
    ArgDesc(2) = "Element number to return"
    ArgDesc(3) = "Single-character element separator"

    Application.MacroOptions _
       Macro:=FuncName, _
       Description:=FuncDesc, _
       Category:=Category, _
       ArgumentDescriptions:=ArgDesc
End Sub
```

Comment: And where exactly do I have to put that routine and what has to stand in it?

Comment: You need to create a routine and call it whatever you like. For example: 'RegisterMyFunction()'. You only need to run it once and then your function will be registered in that workbook; so it does not matter where you place it.